# When using a feature-branch based rebase workflow, how can I keep a branch for minor changes in the master?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-branch-sculpting

I used to use a merge workflow and my current team works with a rebase workflow.

In it, features branches are forked from the master, then rebased with the master and then squash merged onto the master.

I would like to keep a branch for minor changes onto the master that I could easily fit in the feature branches, though, I am unsure about what is the solution that will bring me less problems:

1. fork minor_changes from the master and then merge it onto my feature branches (potentially many of them), and later squash merge the feature branches onto the master.
2. fork minor_changes from the master and then rebase the - potentially many - feature branches with minor_changes, and later squash merge the feature branches onto the master.

I do not know if the first option will cause me any trouble, and I suspect that the 2nd one might duplicate commits in the final history.

Which is the best way to take care of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Checkout ( what you mean by *"fork"* a branch ) `minor_changes` branch from `master`.
2. As changes occur on `master` rebase `minor_changes` branch on to `master`. You could set it up to track the `master` branch with `git branch -u origin/master minor_changes` then simply run `git pull --rebase` to keep it updated.
3. Checkout feature branches from `minor_changes` branch.

Comment: the feature branches are meant to be already existing. I have rebased them to minor_changes

Comment: @PedroMorteRolo Then you simply merge `minor_changes` into the feature branch, since it always represents `master` with your minor changes applied.

Comment: but won't that create problems if two feature branches have merged the same minor_changes commits?

Comment: Merging the same changes twice won't do anything.